# Laravel change eloquent cascading sequence

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the `$persons` collection that contains array of `$person` eloquent object models with relations.
person has many accounts and accounts has one en.

for example if want to access e1 propertie of en the way is : `$person->accounts[0]->en`

How can I turn `$person`  cascading sequence :

```
person=>{
  p1,
  p2,
  accounts{
    a1,
    a2,
    en{
      e1,
      e2
    }
  }
}
```

into something like:

```
en{
  e1,
  e2,
  accounts{
    a1,
    a2
  },
  person{
    p1,
    p2
  }
}
```

after change i want something like this `$en->accounts->person->p1`

Comment: Your question needs more clarifications

Comment: Cascading based on name?

Comment: @DonRaider i edited the post

Answer (score 1):

You can create a relation in En model specifying the relation with Account model.

```
public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);
    }
```

And in Account model, create a relation with Person model.

```
public function person(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

Then you will be able to retrieve the data as you asked like

```
//en should have account and account should be associated with person
$en->accounts->person->get();
```

Comment: .thanks, but this is collection layer problem. 
i want to chenge object secuence and this sould be done by one of the collection api.